# Variable always empty

Tags: c++, initialization, global, lifetime, temporary

I'm having troubles initializing a global variable. My C++ is a bit rusty so I can't remember the reason why my code isn't working.

**file.cpp**

```
const char * write_path = &(std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo")[0];

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    std::cout << "printing a string: ";
    std::cout << (std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo\n");

    std::cout << "printing a const char*: ";
    std::cout << &(std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo")[0] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "printing write_path:";
    std::cout << write_path;
    std::cout << write_path << std::endl;

    std::cout << "printing FIFO_PATH:" << std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH"));
}
```

As a premise: FIFO_PATH has been correctly added to bashrc, and it works, however, when I launch this program this is the output:

```
printing a string: /home/Processes/FIFOs/pythonread_fifo
printing a const char*: /home/Processes/FIFOs/pythonread_fifo
printing write_path:
printing FIFO_PATH:/home/Processes/FIFOs
```

As you can see `write_path` is completely empty.

What's even stranger to me is that if I define write_path as:

```
 const char * write_path = "/home/Processes/FIFOs/pythonread_fifo";
```

Then `write_path` is no longer empty, it's correctly initialized and printed.

How can I solve this? Or at the very least, why is this happening?

EDIT: The issue IS NOT related to `write_path` being global. I placed the definition inside the main and when I try to print `write_path`, it's still empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`write_path` is initialized as a pointer pointing to the 1st element of a [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) `std::string`, which will be destroyed immediately after the full expression, left `write_path` dangled, dereference on it leads to UB.

You can use `std::string` directly, or use a named `std::string`, then get the pointer from it.

```
std::string s = std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo";
const char * write_path = &s[0]; // or s.c_str()
```

On the other hand,

```
const char * write_path = "/home/mverrocc/dss_cp/dss-cp/Processes/FIFOs/pythonread_fifo";
```

works fine, the [c-style string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) has [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and exists in memory for the life of the program, then `write_path` is always a valid pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char * write_path = &(std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo")[0];
```

constructs a temporary `std::string`, takes the address of it's first character then discards the string, thus deleting the underlying char array. This is UB.

Better just use `std::string` and use `c_str()` when you need a `const char*`

Comment: God, I knew my C++ was rusty, just not THIS rusty... I completely forgot that the temporary string would've been deallocated...

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a *temporary* `std::string` object, and get a pointer to its first character. This pointer will become invalid as soon as the expression `&(std::string(getenv("FIFO_PATH")) + "/pythonread_fifo")[0]` ends, when the temporary object is destructed.

Use a `std::string` object for `write_path` as well, define it inside the `main` function, and use the `c_str` function of the string when you need a null-terminated string.